# An example of how to call admin.setRestrictionInfo from PHP SDK

Tags: facebook

This is what I got so far and the returned result is empty

```
$params = array(
     "method"=>"admin.setRestrictionInfo",
     "restriction_str"=>"{'age':'21+'}"
);
$this->fb->api($params)
```

According to this page
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Session_Secret_and_API_Methods

I need to pass the Application Secret along with this type of API call, but I can't figure it out how to do it with PHP SDK.

Any inputs, directions would be appreciate as well

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

simple

```
$this->fb->setSession(); //set user session to null
$params = array(
     "method"=>"admin.setRestrictionInfo",
     "restriction_str"=>array("age"=>18+)
);
$this->fb->api($params);
```